# Loading website in Google Chrome randomly, sporadically results in "Waiting for www..." infinitely

Tags: html, google-chrome, caching, browser-cache

I've been using Google Chrome to visit a website that I manage. The website loads every day without problem as expected. I refresh, it loads fine again, and over and over. But then occasionally, with absolutely no other external input or changes, I will refresh the webpage and randomly Chrome will not load the website under any circumstances. The tab sits with the spinning wheel forever, and the bottom simply says "Waiting on www.mywebsite.com..." ...forever. The site can work for a couple days without incident, but then seconds after it works, it stops.

Let's say I have two tabs open, and one of them is MyWebsite and that tab freezes in this manner. If I'm on google.com in the second tab tab, and I type in mywebsite.com, it will remain on the Google.com page, but show the "waiting for MyWebsite.com..." status update on the bottom endlessly. We've left it for hours before. It's like it gets stuck just requesting the website.

THEN if I wait an arbitrary period of time, usually less than an hour but *always* longer than about 20 minutes with no other changes, and I refresh or try in a new tab, the website will rapidly load as though nothing has happened.

I'm using the latest version of Chrome, 46.0.2490.86 (64-bit), and on the latest Mac OSX El Capitan 10.11.1

**Here's what I've tried:**

1) I've been able to verify that it is NOT the website. The website WILL load without incident on Firefox, Safari, mobile browsers, et al *while* it will not load in Chrome. Additionally, while Chrome is stuck in "waiting for website", pinging, tracert, and website availability tests all show it functional. And I should point out again that the website will work on Chrome all the time, all day, and even for 24 hours, but then the exact same page (it's indiscriminate about WHICH page it freezes on) that loaded sometimes literally 5 seconds ago, will freeze indefinitely.

2) I have no extensions running on Chrome of any kind.

3) I went to google://net-internals -> Socket and flushed all sockets and it makes no difference.

4) A hard refresh makes no difference.

5) This happens at random intervals. The website will load and refresh fine for hours. Then one time, it simply freezes. When it does this, closing the tab and opening a new one makes no difference. *Flushing the cache makes no difference.* No matter what, if you type in mywebsite.com, it will not load a single element of the site and instead simply do nothing but say waiting for website. We've been absolutely unable to see any pattern as to when it simply stops.

6) I am unable to verify if this happens with other websites, because I do not use other website nearly as frequently, and since the problem is random, it's hard to replicate for another site.

7) Shutting down Chrome entirely and turning it back on makes no difference.

8) This does seem to happen when I'm refreshing the site a lot. Let's say I made a minor css change, or it's a busy day and I've refreshed several times in the last 30 minutes to retrieve the latest ecommerce orders, it tends to happen with more frequency. So my suspicion is something having to do with the cache (though again, clearing the cache doesn't make a difference).

When this happens, usually no code has been changed on the back end, nothing has to have changed about the website itself whatsoever. It's been doing this for weeks and weeks.

Can anyone shine some light on this situation? It's incredibly frustrating.